# Book, video or website for enthusiastic outdoor physics experiments

Tags: resource-recommendations

Could anyone suggest a book or website which can help me on seeing some fantastic physics experiments which should be done in outdoors or need big instruments and space to be done?

Comment: Are you asking about real experiments that you could visit for a "your tax dollars at work" tour or about theoretical experiments that physicists would love to do if there were no budget constraints?

Comment: for not very expensive real experiments which could be done for high school students...

Comment: I see. You want to go really big? Have the students measure the diameter of Earth with the method of Eratosthenes... baseline... at least several hundred miles. :-)

Comment: not that much big as you go... but that's good if it does not cost much... ;)

Comment: It's just an angle measurement and teaches trigonometry. You need to get two schools to do the measurement at the same time and synchronize with a phone call. I think that's an interesting twist and it should teach students how large collaborations of scientists work these days, using phone calls and video conferences.